# How to stay in position when new messages are loaded in a ScrollView in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a ScrollView containing messages (most recent messages are further) in a chat application.

I limit the number of pre-loaded messages, and I dynamically load a new batch when the Scroll View is scrolled to the top. So when new messages are loaded, the current scrollPos is at 0.

The problem is that when the new messages arrive, the scrollPos stays at 0, so the user is teleported to the oldest newly loaded message.

I have tried to deal with it by manually scrolling back down to the position using the size of the content change, but this is not satisfying as the user sees a back and forth scrolling.

Can someone think of a way to do this so that the user does not see any change when the new messages appear an can simply gradually scroll up to see them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way to do it.
The idea comes from the Invertible Scroll View component: https://github.com/expo/react-native-invertible-scroll-view

I didn't use the component but implemented the idea directly on the Scroll View to have minimal changes in my code.

To explain, we translate vertically the Scroll View using the style of the Scroll View and transform: `[{ scaleY: -1 }]`. We do the same for the children. Then, we revert the order of the messages.

In that setup, the scrollPos() measures from the visual bottom. To trigger the loading of the new messagges, now I use

```
const isCloseToBottom = ({layoutMeasurement, contentOffset, contentSize}) => {
  const paddingToBottom = 20;
  return layoutMeasurement.height + contentOffset.y >=
    contentSize.height - paddingToBottom;
};
```

The trick is that now, when the new messages appear on top, you have nothing to do as the distance from the user's point of view to the bottom does not change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onContentSizeChange prop to scroll to the bottom anytime it detects a change in content size.

The `scrollToEnd` function may differ depending on RN version.

```
<ScrollView
  ...
  onContentSizeChange={() => this.scrollView.scrollToEnd({animated: true})}>
</ScrollView>
```

Ref: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrolltoend

Comment: I don't want to scroll to the bottom
I want to visually stay where I was before the contentSizeChange
But the scrollPosition should change and I can't figure a way to make it smooth

Comment: Just for my understanding, so when the user manually scrolls to the top, you load a new batch of messages and scroll position is at 0. In the meantime, a new batch of messages is received and the user is auto scrolled to the top again - is that correct? 

What would you like to happen after the second batch is recieved and the scroll position is at 0? Don't move at all? 

Also, try share some code - be much better to guide.

Comment: When user scrolls to top (scrollPos = 0), loading is triggered. When new messages arrive, scrollPos still equals 0, so user is by default shown the top (so the new messages). I want to avoid this, and keep the user seeing what he was seeing before the new messages arrived. I can manually scroll down to what the user was seeing before using onContentSizeChange, but the small delay makes the process not smooth at all. Thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: Can you add a check when the loading is triggered, to say if scrollPos = 0 then do nothing?

Comment: Have a look at the method i found in my answer above !